# If A,B are two non empty bounded subsets of R, A-B = {a-b| a belongs to A, b belongs to B} then prove that inf(A-B)=inf(A)-inf(B). Please help me?

Tags: real-analysis

I proved the existence of inf A, inf B and inf(A-B). I'm not getting the inclusion. How can I use, inf A = - sup(-A) in this?

Comment: This is false, for instance $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, $\inf(A-B)=-1$.

Comment: this came in the exams several times.

Comment: Not in the ones I have gone to.

Answer (score 2):

I think the true result is $\inf(A-B)=\inf(A)-\sup(B)$. Proof

Let $a$ be $\inf(A)$ and $b$ be $\sup(B)$. Then for every $x∈ A$, you have $x\ge a$ and for every $y∈ B$, you have $y\le b$. So, for all $(x-y)∈(A-B)$, you have $(x-y)\ge (a-b)$ and so $\inf(A-B)\ge (a-b)$.

But for all $\varepsilon>0$ you can find $x∈ A$ with $x\le a+\varepsilon/2$ and find $y∈ B$ with $y\ge b-\varepsilon/2$ so you can find an element $(x-y)∈(A-B)$ with $(x-y) \le (a-b)+\varepsilon$ and so you have $\inf(A-B)\le (a-b)$.

Comment: Is it possible to make the sup(B) as sup(-B)?

Comment: Nope, usually $\sup(B)$ is different from $\sup(-B)$. The only case in which they are equal is when $B$ is symmetric wrt the origin (so $x∈ B$ if and only if $(-x)∈ B$). You can do $\sup(B)=-\inf(-B)$ I think

Comment: Thank you everyone!